# move minicom to background after activation

Tags: serial-port, minicom

there is a way to move minicom to bg after I entered?
I know I can use '&' at the end of the command to start minicom on bg.
but after I moved it to fg, how I can move it back to bg?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your background/foreground processes with giving their job number to **fg**/**bg** commands as an argument. You can view all jobs' number and status, which started at existing session, with `jobs` command.

Let me give you an example. You've started `python3 -m http.server 8080 &` , then `python3 -m http.server 80`.  As you can see server on port **80** on foreground, and port **8080** on background. Then you changed your mind, and wanted to **8080** on foreground, and **80** on background. Firstly you need
to send stop signal to **8080** with *Ctrl-Z* keystroke or `kill -19 <PID>` command. Then you put **8080** on background with `bg %2` or just `bg`. Then put **80** on foreground with `fg %1`. That's it.

In your case, just stop the foreground process, then put it on background.

NOTE: If no argument given to **bg**/**fg** commands, command will be automatically applied to last job started at existing session.

Comment: That's not working with minicom, there is no Ctrl-Z

Comment: Then find it's PID(process id) from another terminal, and then send SIGSTOP signal with `kill -19 <PID>` command. You can find it's PID with `ps aux` command. You can filter output with `ps aux | grep minicom`.

Comment: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92248) it says _Ctrl-A_ will pause printing, but I don't know is it equivalent to stop signal or not. In another answer, it says _Ctrl-S_ will stop.